# ViewModel in postback to controller is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

i try to search this problem, but could not find a solution for it, **please help me**:

my viewModel:

```
namespace webShop.ViewModels.Home
{
    public class RegisterUserViewModel
    {
        public UserDB User { get; set; }

        public UsersDetaile UsersDetaile { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<state> state { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my model:

```
public partial class UserDB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }

    public virtual UsersDetaile UsersDetaile { get; set; }
}

public partial class UsersDetaile
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Tell { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
    public byte city { get; set; }
    public byte state { get; set; }
    public string postCode { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public virtual City City1 { get; set; }
    public virtual State State{ get; set; }
    public virtual UserDB UserDB { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{ 
    stateRepository stateRep = new stateRepository();
    var model = new RegisterUserViewModel();
    model.state = stateRep.Select().ToList();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterUserViewModel user) //Problem: postback viewModel is null
{
   //My Code
}
```

and my register view

```
@model webShop.ViewModels.Home.RegisterUserViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", Url = "/Home/Register" }))
{

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <h1 class="block-header">Register</h1>
      <div class="group">
          <label class="label">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="controls">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.User.Name, new { @class = "text" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.User.Name)
          </div>
      </div>

    //....

  <div class="group">
        <label class="label">Address </label>
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.UsersDetaile.address, new { @class = "text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.UsersDetaile.address)
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="controls">
             <button class="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

after press submit **userDB** and **usersDetaile** is ***null***, what can i do?

Comment: Does it work using a regular form?

Comment: Just a side note, shouldn't UsersDetaile be UsersDetails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have ViewModels with complex types... **you need to call the default Constructor of the complex properties**.

```
public class RegisterUserViewModel
{

    public RegisterUserViewModel() {
        User = new UserDB();
        UsersDetaile = new UsersDetaile();
    }

    public UserDB User { get; set; }

    public UsersDetaile UsersDetaile { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<state> state { get; set; }
}
```

This way, the binder can load the properties values. You don't need anything else.

One thing that looks weird, at least, is that your ViewModel has a property called  `UsersDetaile` that is the same name as the type. The same property is inside the `UserDB`. This could make YOU and the binder error prone.

Comment: This works, there is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dAEPAO)

Comment: I had a similar issue once and the constructor fixed it. It should work fine if you add the default constructor.

Comment: You do **not** need to add a default constructor that initializes the complex properties (the `DefaultModelBinder` does this by default)! The issue is that the parameter of the POST method is named `user` and the view model also has a property named `user` so it cant be bound. Change the method signature to `public ActionResult Register(RegisterUserViewModel model)` - or any other name other that the name of a property - and it will work fine.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

To bind nested ViewModels use [templated helpers](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/), they are similar to partial view. So to make your code work:

- Create new folder `EditorTemplates` in your `Home/View` folder
- Add 2 new files `UsersDetaile.cshtml` and `UserDB.cshtml`
- Move your markup related to the classes to these files
- In your main view put this instead: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.User)` and `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UsersDetaile)`